# x86 Assembly, what is wrong with my code? Input, arithmetic, print

Tags: assembly, x86

I need some help with a program I'm trying to write. The program is supposed to read two numbers from standard input, save it and use it to perform basic mathematical operations then return it.

Most of everything is working, I think. But it doesn't print the results properly. It prints a whole bunch of random characters. I believe the problem has to do with the ascii to int or the int to ascii conversion that happens within my code, but I can't be sure.

Here is the portion of my code that reads from input:

```
mov byte    [firstNum], 30
mov byte    [firstNum + 1], 0
mov     ah, 0Ah
mov     edx, firstNum
int     021H
movzx   esi, byte [firstNum+1]
mov     edx, firstNum+2 
add     esi, edx
mov byte    [esi], "$"

mov byte    [secondNum], 30
mov byte    [secondNum + 1], 0
mov     ah, 0Ah
mov     edx, secondNum
int     021H
movzx   esi, byte [secondNum+1]
mov     edx, secondNum+2
add     esi, edx
mov byte    [esi], "$"
```

where:

```
firstNum    resb    32      ; first number
secondNum   resb    32      ; second number
result      resb    32      ; result
```

Now here's the portion that converts the string input to integers, add the two values, converts from integer to string and prints the result:

```
push dword  secondNum+2
call        _atoi
add         esp, 4
mov         ebx, eax
push dword  firstNum+2
call        _atoi
add         esp, 4
add         eax, ebx
push dword  10                  ; base of 10, decimal
push dword  result
push dword  eax
call        _itoa
add         esp, 12
printOut    result
```

I'd really appreciate it if some one can tell me what's wrong with my code. Thanks!

Comment: what is the format of the executable file?

Comment: It's written as nasm (.asm file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one thing that looks wrong is that if `atoi` is the C library version, then you should be terminating the input strings with zeros rather than dollar signs.

We also can't see if the segment registers are set correctly.  For `int 21` to work, `DS` must be set to the segment where the buffers are reserved.

Additionally it looks like `printOut` is a macro.  Since you are getting nonsense output, it's a pretty safe bet that you are setting up the call to this macro incorrectly or else there's an error in the macro itself.  But we don't know how it works, so can't say what's wrong with this section of code.  For example, if `printOut` is using `int 21`, then it will expect a dollar sign terminator, and `itoa` will be using a 0 instead.

When assembly code doesn't work, the debugger is your friend.  Have you tried to single step through the code and see what's happening?

If you don't have a debugger, then remove the input section and try the output section alone: load 42 in eax and convert this to a string and put it to standard output.

Comment: I used the debugger and everything up until the point where it tries to print the result works as it should. I think it might have to do with itoa and it terminating with a 0 and not a $. I found that appending a $ to the end of the string is a simple solution, might not be ideal, but it worked and my result prints out as it should!
Thanks!